# How to Combine a Bridge with VLAN over a Bonding and Two Default Gateways

Tags: linux, interface, vlan, bonding, gateway

I have a Linux server with three NIC that are connected to a switch (one NIC is the management, two NIC form a LACP bonding). In addition I need to use a VLAN (167), because the switch is configured with it.

Huawei switch:

```
interface Eth-Trunk10
description #### Server ####
port link-type trunk
port trunk allow-pass vlan 167
stp disable
mode lacp
load-balance src-dst-mac
```

Now, that is the current configuration:

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp3s0 inet manual

auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet manual
    bond-master bond1

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual
    bond-master bond1

auto bond1
iface bond1 inet manual
    bond-slaves eno1 enp4s0
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-mode 802.3ad
    bond-lacp-rate 1

auto bond1.167
iface bond1.167 inet static
    address x.x.x.x
    netmask 255.255.255.248
    vlan-raw-device bond1

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address  a.a.a.b
    netmask  255.255.255.248
    gateway a.a.a.a
    bridge-ports enp3s0
    bridge-stp off
```

As you can see, there is an initial bridging interface (vmbr0) from the virtual hosting system, which is the management interface right now.

**Later on all the traffic, with the exception of management, shall be going over the bonding interface using VLAN 167 and I guess, I will need two default gateways.**

So, I think I have to change everything to this:

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp3s0 inet static
    address  a.a.a.b
    netmask  255.255.255.248
    post-up ip route add a.a.a.0/24 dev enp3s0 src a.a.a.b table rt1
    post-up ip route add default via a.a.a.a dev enp3s0 table rt1
    post-up ip rule add from a.a.a.b/32 table rt1
    post-up ip rule add to a.a.a.b/32 table rt1
    post-up ip route add default via a.a.a.a metric 101 dev enp3s0
    post-down ip rule del from 0/0 to 0/0 table rt1
    post-down ip rule del from 0/0 to 0/0 table rt1

auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet manual
    bond-master bond1

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual
    bond-master bond1

auto bond1
iface bond1 inet manual
    bond-slaves eno1 enp4s0
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-mode 802.3ad
    bond-lacp-rate 1

auto bond1.167
iface bond1.167 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device bond1

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address x.x.x.y
    netmask 255.255.255.248
    bridge-ports bond1.167
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
    post-up ip route add x.x.x.0/29 dev vmbr0 src x.x.x.y table rt2
    post-up ip route add default via x.x.x.x dev vmbr0 table rt2
    post-up ip rule add from x.x.x.y/32 table rt2
    post-up ip rule add to x.x.x.y/32 table rt2
    post-up ip route add default via x.x.x.x metric 100 dev vmbr0
    post-down ip rule del from 0/0 to 0/0 table rt2
    post-down ip rule del from 0/0 to 0/0 table rt2
```

/etc/iproute2/rt_tables:

```
101 rt1
102 rt2
```

Adresses explained:

```
x.x.x.0 = net for internet access and bridging vms to internet
x.x.x.x = gateway
x.x.x.y = ip for vmbr0/bonding

a.a.a.0 = net for management
a.a.a.a = gateway
a.a.a.b = ip for management/enp3s0
```

Now my two questions are:

1. Is the VLAN 167 configured correctly with bond1.167 under vmbr0, so all the traffic from the hosts and virtual machines are going through it? I have a feeling, there is something wrong there.
2. Is this setup with two gateways working? Can I still use the management interface enp3s0 this way? My plan is to block management access on the bonding interface (vmbr0/bond1.167), but leaving it open on the management interface, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Yes, the bond-then-VLAN-then-bridge and the host IP address on the bridge interface is the expected arrangement.

2.) I must ask: **does your management interface really need to be directly connectable from anywhere in the internet?**

If the management interface needs to be accessible from a small number of network segments only, you could use more limited routes for its gateway. With no need for a *default* gateway on the management interface, your routing could be greatly simplified.

For example, if you know your management workstations are in network a.a.c.0/24 and remote management VPN endpoints are in a.a.d.224/27, and those are the only ways the management access should be used, you could specify the management interface like this:

```
iface enp3s0 inet static
    address  a.a.a.b
    netmask  255.255.255.248
    post-up ip route add a.a.c.0/24 via a.a.a.a dev enp3s0
    post-up ip route add a.a.d.224/27 via a.a.a.a dev enp3s0
    # no default gateway on this interface, intentionally!
```

and then your `vmbr0` could be simply

```
auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address x.x.x.y
    netmask 255.255.255.248
    gateway x.x.x.x
    bridge-ports bond1.167
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
```

Comment: Thank you, mate. I did that now with only one gateway and one route to the management interface. I still will have to configure something, so nobody can reach this interface.